# Spatialite union more than two layers / tables

Tags: layers, sql, spatialite, sqlite, union

Is there a way to union or collect any number of layer geometries with Spatialite (or another spatial database)? Two is simple enough, but more than that becomes convoluted. For example, if all I want is all the geometries of four layers, I need to do:

```
SELECT ST_Collect(ST_Collect(tbl1.geom, tbl2.geom), ST_Collect(tbl3.geom, tbl4.geom))
FROM tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4
```

Is there a function or approach which would allow for something like ST_Collect(tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4)?

Comment: As you can see from the documentation https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html ST_Collect takes either one or two "geom". So tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4 clearly will not work.

Comment: @user30184 Yes, I know this. I am asking for an alternative approach that would replicate the same idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try UNION ALL for collecting all the geometries before running ST_COLLECT.

```
SELECT ST_Collect(geometry) FROM
(SELECT geometry from tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT geometry from tbl2
UNION ALL
SELECT geometry from tbl3
UNION ALL
SELECT geometry from tbl4);
```

Comment: This works and is more transparent than my existing method, which feels like a workaround, thanks.